# gen_word2vec in tensorflow is not found

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, word2vec

As I ran the code (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec.py) in my laptop(Mac,python3), I received an error:

```
    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.models.embedding.gen_word2vec' has no attribute 'skipgram_word2vec'
```

tensorflow has been installed and working in my laptop. It seems like "gen_word2vec" is missing. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the latest version of TensorFlow.